# Using Authorization filters to Implement permission based authorization in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-authorization

I'm new to ASP.NET Core, and I have been trying to look for a way to implement permission-based authorization where a user has to have a certain permission to access a particular action. As I was going through Microsoft Authorization documentation, they explained how to achieve this by using a custom IAuthorizationPolicyProvider which I have understood but not yet tried it out.
But my question is, Is there any problem or is it okay if I use a custom parameterized authorization filter to do the same?

public class HasPermissionAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        private readonly string permission;

```
    public HasPermissionAttribute(string permission)
    {
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = context.HttpContext.User;
        if (user.HasClaim("Permission", permission))
        {
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

And use the filter as seen below

public class HomeController : Controller
    {

```
    [HasPermission("User_Edit")
    public IActionResult EditUser()
    {
        var user = HttpContext.User;
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

From the code above, what if I add some custom claims of type "Permission" then use them to authorization a user.

Is there any drawback to doing it this way or should I stick to creating a custom IAuthorizationPolicyProvider?

I am a beginner, and I think this way is too easy and that kinda makes me think that it's not really the right way of achieving what I want to achieve. Any feedback will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommend way is to use policy based approach , generate the policies dynamically with a custom `AuthorizationPolicyProvider` using custom authorization attribute .

From [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31465227/5751404) :

> We don't want you writing custom authorize attributes. If you need to do that we've done something wrong. Instead you should be writing authorization requirements.

Similar discussion [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5607) is also for your reference .

Comment: I've gone through the discussion, though the solution you/they provide is efficient and I agree with it,. but I would like to know if there are any negative effects if I do it the way I described above ( for the sake of learning and gaining a deeper understanding of this topic )

Comment: No obvious negative . In fact , i would say use custom attribute also effective in your scenario . But the recommend way is to use policy which suggested by asp.net core team .